# How to calculate the percentage of distribution in each polygon?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon

I have binary map for disease suitable area and I want to calculate the percentage using pixel count in each polygon how can I do that?

I use zonal histogram and do have frequency for each polygon is there is way to use this values to calculate the percentage in each polygon?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: I use Arc.GIS 10

Comment: You need to provide more deteails. What do you mean by binary map? what do you mean by 'calculate the percentage'?

Comment: I guess that by 'Binary Map' - @Basma Sheta meant a raster that containt pixel information for either it is suitable for disease or not. Calculating the percentage can be performed by summerize the area of the pixels for each type (suitable or not) in each polygon (count the pixels in each polygon and multiple the count with the area of each pixel using cell size), than divide it by polyogn area. Don't know arc functions to perform it though.

Comment: Yes this is really what I want to do. I use zonal histogram but it calculate the frequency in each polygon (suitable and unsuitable). I don't know how to calculate this count for each polygon.

Comment: I did suitability map for disease I reclass it as suitable and non suitable so the binary map I have now iclue (0 non suitable) and (1 suitable area) what I want to do to calculate the percentage of infection 
(suitable area) in each polygon so my question is what is the method I can do to calculate that. I did use zonal histogram it gives me frequency in each polygon is this can help to this calculation.

Comment: Can you edit your original question (click edit under the question) to turn the various comments into a single coherent question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "[Zonal statistics as table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm)"-Tool (and check to calculate "all statistics"), you should get everything you need to calculate percentages in the output table. There will be a field "count" which represents the number of pixels in the zone, and the field "sum" will have the number of pixels where your binary grid has the value one in each zone. From there it should be straightforward to calculate percentages.

Comment: I will warn you that I have had a bug logged with ESRI for two years not regarding exactly this issue. I have found that the counts on large rasters are incorrect. I have run  "Zonal statistics as table" 4 times on the same data and gotten 4 different counts. I have not figured out what the raster size needs to be for this to pop up and it does not seem to be an issue on smaller rasters. I think that it is related to the pyramid-tiling used for larger rasters.

Comment: Is this still an issue with 10.2, where Zonal Stats was completley rewritten (at least I believe so since it now uses multi-processing and is lightning fast)?

Comment: Zonal stat internally convert the vector to a raster for he processing. If you don't manage this, the size will be selected arbitrarily, which can cause resampling and rounding errors.